# How to Change then Number format in Materilaize input field?

Tags: css, material-design

I've searching to find out a way how to change the input number format in Materialize CSS but didn't find any so far. Is there a way you can change the input number format?
[image]

```
<div class="row" >
        <div class="input-field col offset-s4 s4">
          <input id="price" type="number" class="validate"  >
          <label for="price">Price</label>
        </div></div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col offset-s4 s4 ">
          <input id="DownPay" type="number" class="validate" >
          <label for="DownPay">Down Payment</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done by `type="number"` [Reason](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/datatypes.html#common.data.float)

you need `type=text` with some JS

```js
document.getElementById('Price').addEventListener('input', event =>
  event.target.value = (parseInt(event.target.value.replace(/[^\d]+/gi, '')) || 0).toLocaleString('en-US')
);
```

```html
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            

<div class="input-wrap">
<div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="Price" type="text" id="" pattern="^[\d,]+$" class="validate">
          <label for="Price">Price</label>
        </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working, I'm using https://materializecss.com/ will your code work with it?

Comment: Its work for all what ever library you are using i have updated my answer with materializecss

Comment: I'm still having a problem even though I've done the changes you've instructed, can you check my work have I done correctly? here is my link https://script.google.com/d/1M9YYZIGXpOvmMZ9ESEh14HYfbshEoV9s9YqarYSg1qh8pEyV4G-Ki3rj/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil just create the working example of your code just like i did above in my snippet.

Comment: I've done exactly as you've given, still I have no idea where I went wrong :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222658/discussion-between-muhammed-aadhil-and-awais).